# MicroPython Visual Studio Code "import *.py" in Pico

Tags: python, visual-studio-2012, raspberry-pi-pico

I have the Sensor.py file in the same folder as my Main.py
I get this message: ImportError: no module named 'Sensor'

How can I import .py files?

I've tried all import options.

Answer (score 0):

Run in your terminal

```bash
pip install sensor
```

Answer (score 0):

I need to save the `sensor.py` first, then upload it to the pico, and then I can play the `main.py`.
The `sensor.py` was missing on the pico. Simply clicking main.py on run is not enough.